# StackOverflow like routing redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating a website that has routes pretty similar to SO, in that they are:

```
posts/{id}/{title}
```

I want to copy the functionality where for any given route `X`

anything that starts with `/posts/{id}` and has an incorrect title, gets rerouted to `/posts/{id}/{title}`

doing so in the controller seems pretty awkward, but doing it at routing level seems even worse.

I guess the controller would be the way to go.

```
public ActionResult Display(long id, string title)
{
    // try and find post
    // if post is null, error

    // if post.title != title, permanent redirect to correct title
    if (title != "correct-ness-ly")
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Display", new { id, title = "correct-ness-ly" });
    }

    // permanent redirect if name doesn't match
    return new ContentResult { Content = "display post-id : {0}, {1}".FormatWith(id, title) }; // found or not
}
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to accomplish this?

**Update** I just realized this makes me "lose" any querystring values there might be. Besides having to declaratively pass each action argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of IIS you are using. But for 7+ you can use the [redirect module](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect).

For IIS 6 there were several third party URL Redirect modules that could be used.

Comment: I'm using IIS 7.5, but I don't really have access to IIS on the production server